# How to identify Amazon Fire TV and Fire Stick in code level (HTML/JavaScript) ..?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-fire-tv

I have developed a Fire TV application using HTML5 and JavaScript. Here I need to identify what is the currently accessing device. Either Amazon Fire TV or Amazon Fire Stick.

How can I do this using HTML/JavaScript..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to distinguish them by checking the [user agent string](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/user-agent-strings) which has the [device model](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/device-and-platform-specifications).

`android.os.Build.MODEL`

- `AFTB` (Fire TV Gen 1)
- `AFTS` (Fire TV Gen 2)
- `AFTM` (Fire
  TV Stick Gen 1)
- `AFTT` (Fire TV Stick Gen 2)